# Do we need to build an inequality for $|x+4| -4 =x $?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

$$|x+4| -4 =x $$

I've two questions about this equation.

- Why do we need to build an inequality?
- If we build an inequality, in what cases do we need to analyse?

Also I'm trying to find the negative values that $x$ can take.

Comment: $x$ is real here and for $ y\ge0, |y|=+y$

Comment: Another approach besides the cases would be to graph the functions $y=|x-4|$ and $y=x+4$ and see where they intersect.

Comment: I think I've written it wrong. It ought to be  $|x+4| -4 = 0$.

Comment: That's equal to x.

Comment: $|x+4| -4 = x$ That's it.

Comment: I notified the people who answered the question before it was changed of the change in the problem statement.  However, you should not change a question after it has been answered since it makes correct answers look incorrect.  Instead, you should pose a new question.

Comment: The $|u|=u$ holds only for $u \geq 0$, in your case $u=x+4\geq 0$ and so $x\geq -4$ and you are done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reasoning for your new question is the same.

There are two cases for killing of the absolute value:

1. $x\geq-4$, which gives $x+4-4=x,$ which says that the equation has infenitely many solutions in this case:

Any number from the set  $[-4,+\infty)$ is valid;

2. $x<-4$, which gives $-x-4-4=x$ or $x=-4$, which is not valid in this case.

The answer is: $[-4,+\infty).$

Comment: Are you sure? However, we're finding the negative values that $x$ can take.

Comment: @Fiv  I am sure that your equation has an unique root: $0$. What is your negative root?

Comment: The question was changed after you posed your answer.  It now reads $|x + 4| - 4 = x$.

Comment: Thank you. I'll also change my post.

Answer (score 1):

Building an inequality for cases $x < -4$ and $x \ge -4$ is simply in order to make things easier. Because,

**Case 1 $(x < -4)$:** In this case, $|x+4| = -x-4$ so we have $-x-4-4 = x \implies x = -4$ but $-4 \not\lt -4$ so this solution is not valid for this case.

**Case 2 $(x \ge -4)$:** In this case, $|x+4| = x+4$ so we have $x+4-4 = x \implies 0 = 0$ so for all $x \ge-4$, this equation holds (Notice that it also includes the solution from case 1, which was not valid). So the answer is equation holds for all $x \ge -4$.

Comment: The question was changed after you posed your answer.  It now reads $|x + 4| - 4 = x$.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that, thank you for notification :)

Comment: Be careful.  $x = -4$ is not in the domain in case 1.

Comment: You're right again, thank you for the correction

Answer (score 1):

First of all, note that this isn’t an inequality, but an equation. There are two methods to solve this:

- Case by case analysis: Note that the equation can be written as: $$|x+4|= x +4 $$ When $x\leq -4$, we know that $(x+4)\leq 0$, hence, $|x+4|=-4-x$. Thus, it boils down to solving: $$-4-x=x+4 \implies x = -4$$ which is valid in the range.
  When $x > -4$, we know that $(x+4)>0$, hence, $|x+4|=x+4$. Thus, it boils down to solving $$x+4=x+4 \implies \text{ Holds } \forall x>-4$$
- By squaring: Note that when we square the absolute value, we can get rid of the anonymity surrounding it, thus: $$|x+4|=x+4 \implies |x+4|^2=(x+4)^2 \implies x^2+8x+16 = x^2+8x + 16 \implies \text{ Holds } \forall x\geq -4$$

Note that the second method is easier than the first.

Comment: Did you mean to say that when $x \leq -4$, $x + 4 \leq 0$?